# Working with massive numbers and minute numbers simultaneously

Tags: matlab, matrix, floating-point-precision, numerical

I have an `mxn` matrix A, with very small or very large elements. For example:

```
A = -1e4*randn(10,20);
```

I would like to create a new matrix C of the same size, as follows:

First, define a matrix B whose elements are the exponential of the elements of A:

```
B = exp(A)
```

Then, the matrix C is defined such that each column of C is proportional to the corresponding column of B and the sum of each column of C is equal to 1. In other words, if we take an element of B and divide it by the sum of all the elements of the same columns, then we obtain the corresponding element of C:

```
C = bsxfun(@rdivide,B,sum(B));
```

Mathematically:

[image]

Clearly, all the elements of C are between 0 and 1. However, when computing using the following code, the obtained matrix contains many NaNs:

```
A = -1e4*randn(10,20);

B = exp(A);

C = bsxfun(@rdivide,B,sum(B));

sum(sum(isnan(ee)))
```

I hope somebody can suggest a way to overcome this issue. Thank you very much in advance.

**Update:** Please note that the goal is the matrix C. I defined the matrix B just for explanation purpose, and we may not have to compute it. (We shouldn't actually. As @EJG89 pointed out that B contains only Inf and 0).

**Update 2:** Thanks to @EJG89 for the link to the [Log Sum of Exponentials technique](http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/06/25/log-sum-of-exponentials/), which might be useful. I'm working on finding similar analytical tricks for my problem.

**Update 3:** As suggested by @Dan and @EJG89, we can subtract each column with a constant to obtain a new matrix within a reasonable range. Clearly, we have

[image]

for any constant C. We can choose C as the maximum value of each column:

[image]

(a_{max,j} is the maximum of the j-th column), then

[image]

**I feel that this choice might give a very good approximation, but I don't know how good it is** :|

The new code is:

```
A = bsxfun(@minus,A,max(A));
B = exp(A);
C = bsxfun(@rdivide,B,sum(B));
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to adjust *A* to some new *A'* such that *e<sup>A</sup> = Ce<sup>A'</sup>* where *C* is a constant (that is much less than 1). In other words you're looking for some *k* such that *k.e<sup>A</sup>* is small enough not to breach `ndoublemax` or `eps`. But we want this *k* to be applied to *A* so we need to get it into the exponent. *k = e<sup>ln(k)</sup>* and e<sup>ln(k)</sup>.e<sup>A</sup> = **e<sup>A + ln(k)</sup>** therefore if we add or subtract a number from `A`, *e<sup>A</sup>* is proportionally effected. Or *A' = A + ln(k)*

unfortunately I think that your range is simply too large for any *ln(k)* to stop you from breaching the limits on Matlab doubles. If you add a big number you'll get all of `B` equal to `inf` and if you subtract a big number you'll get all of `B` equal to zero.

So you need to find some way to work with both massive number and minute numbers simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for the answer. I don't think that we have exp(A) = C*exp(A'). Instead, we have exp(a_i) = C*exp(a_i') where a_i and a_i' are respectively the i-th column of A and A', and of course the constant C is different from column to column (what I would like to have is that the sum of the elements of any columns of A' equals 1).

Comment: Dan, do you think that subtracting each column with its maximum element will give a good enough approximation?

Comment: @Nesbit If you want to normalize each column independently, but your data is still `-1e4*randn(10,20)`, then I'm pretty sure you're still going to have the same problem. You want the exponent of numbers in the order of 10000 and -10000 which is going to give you some numbers too big for Matlab to handle as doubles and others to small for Matlab to distinguish from 0, that problem remains weather you're normalizing globally for the matrix or in a column-wise fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Direct method is impossible.

```
A = -1e4*randn(10,20);
B = exp(A);
```

The problem is that B already yields Inf or 0.

Yielding division impossible returning Nan's.

```
ndoublemax = realmax
nsinglemax = realmax('single')

ndoublemin = realmin
nsinglemin = realmin('single')
```

yielding:

ndoublemax =

1.7977e+308

nsinglemax =

3.4028e+038

ndoublemin =

2.2251e-308

nsinglemin =

1.1755e-038

So your values for B clearly exceed those values.

An approximation can be made by rewriting the exponentials [using this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140730121436/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/06/25/log-sum-of-exponentials/)

So first rewrite to:
log(Cij) = log (exp(Aij)/sumk(exp(A(kj))))

log(Cij) = Aij - log( sumk(exp(A(kj)))

In which the last term can be approximated by:
m = maxk(A(kj))

log(sumk(exp(A(kj))) = m + log(exp(A(kj)-m))

This results in smaller values able to be handled by MatLab, i.e. a normalization so to speak. Still no exact answer though because some values become zero removing their sometimes significant contribution.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that, but I think there should be some way to compute C whose elements are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Look for an analytical solution instead of trying to compute in between products, MatLab is (and computers are) limited.

Comment: Added a analytical way to increase stability at the loss of the smaller numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I had been working on similar analytical tricks for my problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion of @EJG89, you can substitute infinite values with the maximum representable number, and then add `eps` to all the number in the denominator. In this way, you avoid the `Inf`.

```
A = -1e4*randn(10,20);

B = exp(A);
B(isinf(B)) = realmax;

C = bsxfun(@rdivide,B,sum(B)+eps);

sum(isnan(C(:)))
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - it will just replace the NaNs with 0s or 1s which isn't right. The answer must be some adjustment of `A` such that the resultant `B` is still proportionate to `exp(A)`

Comment: Well, it depends on the approach. In this case, we either truncate the range of values or we loose resolution. Without further information, I chose the easiest solution XD

Comment: I guess you might at well replace the `inf`s in `B` with `1` and everything else with `0` to get a rough approximation and just skip the `bsxfun` step

Comment: It happens you can approach the log of a sum by normalizing.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to resort to symbolic computation:

```
A = -1e4*randn(10,20);
S = sym(A,'d'); %// convert to symbolic
C = exp(S)./repmat(sum(exp(S)),size(S,1),1);
```

The result `C` is given in symbolic form. For example, the first column will be something like

```
>> C(:,1)
ans =
   2.9347694526167482187885232843876*10^(-790)
  1.548257079197982942994953632259*10^(-10497)
  8.4257350773369612716806306890481*10^(-6390)
  3.1937456016712092927990884814437*10^(-7937)
  4.0377045095817442881784227420794*10^(-4076)
                                           1.0
  3.3704875581881026436375125643672*10^(-6482)
 8.9221015470879963245101895439354*10^(-12246)
 9.4968643813486260650483647051531*10^(-11252)
 1.8777491443104052522832960625121*10^(-11084)
```

But note that even with symbolic computation the largest term is given as 1, when actually it is (slightly) smaller. Of course, if you then convert to double you only get 0 or 1 values:

```
>> Cd = eval(C);
>> Cd(:,1)
ans =
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Comment: you can tell MATLAB to give you as much precision as you want from a symbolic expression, so that `1.0` will actually show up as `0.999...999999993577744642`: `vpa(C(6,1),1000)`

Comment: @Amro That's what I thought... but that still gives `1`, even if I ask for 1e6 digits (Matlab R2010b)

Comment: it has to do with how you told `sym` to approximate the numeric values from the beginning. Try `sym(randn(..))*1e4` instead. PS: try 5000 precision first before 1 million, that would take forever to finish :)

Comment: @Amro Still no luck. Must be somthing with my Matlab version. Yes, 1 million digits took a long time, but since I kept getting 1, I had to gradually increase just to make sure :-)

Comment: Hi @Luis and @Amro. This approach seems to be "promising" :D (at least it's better than directly computing the exponential). The rounding (to 1 and 0) is not good though. I tried for `A = 1e4*[1 -0.5; 1 0.5; -0.5 -0.5]` and obtained `C=[0.5 0; 0.5 1; 0 0]`, which is somehow a good approximation. However, for `A = 1e4*[1 -0.5; 0.999 0.5; -0.5 -0.5]` or `A = 1e4*[1 -0.5; 0.9999 0.5; -0.5 -0.5]` the results are not quite acceptable :(

Comment: @Amro and Luis: My bad. The methods gives very good results for the above three examples.

Comment: @Nesbit: just keep in mind that this is doing the computation in [variable-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), and it should remain stored as such. The final results are beyond the range/precision of double floating-point numbers, converting them will just underflow/overflow.